# Any success w/ Lunar on Mac OS X?

Tags: ros, ros-lunar, mac

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anybody tried to install Lunar on a Mac? Any luck?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263010/any-success-w/-lunar-on-mac-os-x?/) by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1247 on 2017-06-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, some people have had success. [Mike Purvis has updated his Mac OS X install script](https://github.com/mikepurvis/ros-install-osx).

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2017-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1